# tab bar in a view based application on the fift view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, nib

hy there,

i have asked a similar question just 3 day ago, but it did not helped me out, so here i am again.
I have made a **VIEW** based application so not a tab bar application, and i want to add a tabbar to it. In the developer library i read how you can do this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html
I was using the tutorial how to add a tabbar with a nib file. But there is only one problem with this the tab bar is created in the app delegate, and that is not what i want, i want my tabbar not on the main view but on the fift view.

Does anyone know a solution, on the internet i read something on how to do it with view didload, or something like that, but i could nog figure it out.

i hope someone can help me with this.

thanks any way.

Comment: I answered your last question, about how to make a TabBarController. But what do you mean with 'fift' view?

Comment: @Mats: With fift view i mean that, i have a first view, thats where the application opens with, then there is a button who takes you to the second view, there is a button who takes you to the third view, and eventualy you reach the fift view, and that is where i want to have the tab bar. Also i have an view based application, so i can use your other tip since that is for tab bar applications. I hope this explains it.

Comment: You use a UINavigationController for switch the views? PS: it's fifth

Answer (score 0):

I think i got the solution:

First change your view base application to a navigation based:
This is your standard template for you main nib:
[image]

Make it like this:
[image]

Add a UINavigationController. Open it and drag the ViewBasedViewController over the existing controller in your UINavigationController.

Go to your App Delegate:

```
@interface ViewBasedAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
@end

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;


 }

//Other code omitted
@end
```

Link the navController outlet to the navigation controller in your NIB.

Make a new class with lets say 'TheTabBarController'.

Add this to your view based controller to add the fifth controller:

```
- (IBAction) addFifthView:(id)sender {
    TheTabBarController *conn = [[TheTabBarController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:conn animated:YES];
    [conn release];
}
```

Implement the TheTabBarController like this:

```
@interface TheTabBarController : UITabBarController {

}

@end

@implementation TheTabBarController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    UIViewController *dummy = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Dummy" bundle:nil];
    dummy.title = @"Dummy title";
    dummy.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIViewController *otherDummy = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Dummy" bundle:nil];
    otherDummy.title = @"Other dummy";
    otherDummy.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dummy,otherDummy,nil]];

    [dummy release];
    [otherDummy release];
}
//Other code omitted
@end
```

Should work like this.

Comment: I could not get it to work, when i build it it say it has an duplicate input or something like that, maybe it has something to do with the fact that it say @end twice.

Comment: You have to put the interface in the .h and the implementation in the .m. Then you have to import the TheTabBarController.h in your class where you allocate it.

Comment: Yeah sure maybe i can email it to you btw, on you profile i saw you are form holland, so in the email we can talk dutch. Because my english is not my biggest talent.

Comment: i did not, i only saw you where from hollan. I was just suggesting i could mail it to you.

Comment: Or i could upload it to my mobileme and give you the download link.

Comment: thanks, this helps. Just one more question is there any way, how you can edit the tabbar view, so the view with red and blue with interface builder, so i can add content to it. without having to programmatically add all the pictures and colors.

Comment: The viewcontrollers are both loaded from a dummy nib. Make own nibs and load those nibs in the setup method for both view controllers. Maybe i can add you to my MSN, you can ask more questions if you want, but i don't know how to give you my msn on a secure way...

Comment: mijn msn is fokke ( punt) dekker (appenstaartje) me ( punt) com

Comment: als iemand op deze manier mij nog wil toevoegen die ik niet ken verwijder ik hem wel weer gewoon.

Comment: Voeg mij maar toe als je wilt: matsyboystijlaart (appenstaartje) hotmail (punt) com